# Get process PID from android to kill

Tags: c#, adb

I want to kill process by PID from android SP using C#
usually I write in commande line as shown the screenshoot

```
adb shell
run-as "com.android.commands.monkey"
ps | grep "com.android.commands.monkey"
kill -9 73254
```

73254 is the PID but it will change every time.
So how do it with C#
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# Kill myphoneexplorer process on SP
adb shell "am force-stop com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client"
sleep 2
# Kill com.android.commands.monkey process on SP
adb shell "run-as com.android.commands.monkey"
adb shell "ps | grep com.android.commands.monkey"
for item in $(adb shell "ps | grep com.android.commands.monkey"); do
    if test "$item" != ""
    then
        arr+=($item)
        echo ${arr[1]}
        adb shell "kill -9 ${arr[1]}"
    fi

done
sleep 2
sleep 10
```